# backbone collection data google map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, backbone.js, underscore.js

I am having trouble getting the data from the collection in the render() function for the map view. I have tried getting the data in multiple ways, but I cannot seem to get it correctly. This is where I am currently at https://jsfiddle.net/huntonas/pt17bygm/89/

```
APP = {};
APP.ArtPiece = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        first_name: null,
        title: null,
        location: null,
        description: null,
        last_name: null,
        longitude: null,
        latitude: null,
        type: null,
        medium: null
    }
});
APP.ArtPieces = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: APP.ArtPiece,
    url: 'https://data.nashville.gov/resource/dqkw-tj5j.json'
});
APP.artPieces = new APP.ArtPieces();

APP.Map = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(36.159480, -86.792112),
        zoom: 8,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
});
APP.map = new APP.Map();

APP.MapView = Backbone.View.extend({
    id: 'map',
    initialize: function () {
        this.collection.fetch();
        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.el, this.model.attributes);
        this.render();
    },
    render: function () {

        this.collection.each(function (artPiece) {
            console.log(artPiece.toJSON());
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(artPiece.latitude, artPiece.longitude),
                title: artPiece.title
            });
            return marker;
        }, this);
        $('#map').replaceWith(this.el);
    }
});
APP.mapView = new APP.MapView({
    model: APP.map,
    collection: APP.artPieces
});
```

but it is not showing anything on the console.log. I assume that is because there is nothing in the collection, but I do not know where to call fetch() on the collection. Any help out there? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is two-fold:

1. `Collection#fetch` is an AJAX call and you don't have anything that is paying attention to when it returns with data for your collection.
2. The `artPiece` inside your `this.collection.each` callback will be a model instance. Models don't store their attributes in properties, they're stored inside the `attributes` property and accessed by `model.get('attribute_name')`.

Fixing the first issue is pretty easy. Call [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) with the `reset: true` option (so that it will trigger a `'reset'` event) and then bind your view's `render` to the collection's `'reset'` event:

```
initialize: function() {
    this.collection.fetch({ reset: true });
    this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    //...
}
```

Now your view's `render` will be called when the collection gets something from the remote server.

Fixing the second is also easy and we'll fix another other issue along the way. When you create a marker, you need to tell it which map to use so you need to add `map: this.map` to the constructor arguments. If we do that and start using `get`, we have:

```
el: '#map',
render: function () {
    this.collection.each(function (artPiece) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: this.map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                artPiece.get('latitude'),
                artPiece.get('longitude')
            ),
            title: artPiece.get('title')
        });
    }, this);
}
```

There's no need to say `id: 'map'` and then call `replaceWith` in `render`, you can just say `el: '#map'` instead.

Updated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/jj8kopyk/

Comment: Your solution worked. Thank you for your help and explanation. Just to edit something in your fiddle, calling the google map needs to be https and the render still needs `$('#map').replaceWith(this.el);` to display the created map, but the items that I had incorrect, your example fixed them. I have a working solution in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/huntonas/pt17bygm/99/). Thank you again!

Comment: If you have `el: '#map'` in your view and remove the `id: 'map'` then you shouldn't need the `replaceWith`.